# номер порта при запросе на REST API endpoint в микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, порты, микросервисы

Я не имею большого опыта в микросервисах и не совсем понимаю как поступить в нижеуказанной ситуации.

Есть два вебсервиса, продюсер и консьюмер. Общаются через Apache Kafka, собственно продюсер кидает периодично сообщения с рандомными id и score, а консьюмер у себя вычисляет и сохраняет в Мапе среднее значение score по каждому id.

Так вот, мне надо реализовать  REST API endpoint, который при предоставлянии id возвращает по нему средний score. Собственно я сделал обычный метод в контроллере консьюмера, который на гэт-запрос вот это и делает. Я проверил на Postman, это конечно работает.

Но как быть когда поднято много инстансов консьюмера, а не один, ведь тогда клиент не знает на какой порт отправлять запрос? Ведь каждый инстанс запускается на порту который выбирается ОС (server.port=0)
В таком случае чтобы всё работало как надо нужно добавлять какие-то дополнительные сервисы или можно обойтись без них сделать как-то подругому?

На всякий случай выкладываю файлы application.properties если нужно для ответа:

```
Продюсер: 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=customers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload.id
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=10

Консьюмер:
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=customers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=customer_group
spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount=10
server.port=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текущей конфигурации ваших сервисов вам нужно просто применить АПИ-шлюз (реверс-прокси) и пропускать клиентские запросы через него. В такой конфигурации клиент уже не будет знать ни о каких портах, он будет просто засылать запрос на адрес http://web-api/resourse а шлюз перенаправлять его на какой-либо экземпляр микросервиса (консюмера). АПИ-шлюзы встречаются как в виде проектов с открытым исходным кодом, которые нужно разворачивать на своём "железе", так и в виде облачных сервисов с оплатой за потребление (как правило, довольно недорогих).

Разумеется, в такой схеме перед вами встанет вопрос доставки изменений списка онлайн-экземпляров вашего консюмера в АПИ-шлюз, но для решения этой задачи также есть ряд готовых решений (в зависимости от шлюза/прокси).